# Rails: Use controller for import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, controller

I have a lot of data in JSON and want to import it to my db. My problem is, that I have several `after_create` and `after_update` methods in my controller, where other stuff is written to the db.

So I was thinking to use the controller for importing the data. I can format my data to be the same format as the params hash. But when I create an instance of the controller, setting the params hash and calling `create` it doesn't find some class variables.

Then I tried to force RSpecs controller test to do the work with a post, but I failed there too. Maybe it's not possible, or there is even a better option to import data using all the hooks in my controllers.

Comment: another thought: Maybe it's easier / faster to only post the actual data to my website. But how to handle the authentication (it's done with devise)?

Comment: `import to db of your json data` is one time? or request level..

Comment: Have you thought about moving some of that code from your controller to the model? I know that doesn't fix your problem but I would think convention holds "skinny controllers, fat models."

Comment: It's actual not my code, and yes, it's a little bit messy ;). The import isn't a one time import, new data gets fetched every night, about 1000 products per night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like [RestClient](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) to post the data to the website itself.

As far as handling authentication, devise supports HTTP basic authentication but it [has to be enabled](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-HTTP-Basic-Authentication).  You can easily use RestClient with HTTP basic authentication if that is an option.  Another option is to use [Token Authentication](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Simple-Token-Authentication-Example) with Devise.

Comment: I tried it with token authentication, that worked! I think I will do it through the controller for now, but will refactor the code step by step ;)